# Return view then action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a link. When used, I want to load a new view and then, automatically, call an action. But I only know to load views with a "return" within an ActionResult method (so I cannot later call another action!).

Perhaps I am simply thinking about the whole thing wrong, but I cannot figure out how to do this any other way.

One thing I tried is to call the action from the view, but something like @Html.ActionLink will require the user to click, whereas I want the action to be triggered automatically.

Edit:

Since a few asked, here is the motivation for what I am trying to do (feel free to suggest better approaches!):

I want to redirect the user to a view while a long process runs, and then automatically redirect the user to the final view. The second action would call the process and redirect the user when it is complete.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What does your other `ActionResult` method do?

Comment: Perhaps there is a better way to do this, but I want to redirect the user to a view while a long process runs, and then automatically redirect the user to the final view. The second action would call the process and redirect the user when it is complete.

Comment: You could redirect the user to the first view, and in that view use ajax to call the 2nd method, and in its success callback, redirect to the final view

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: I notice I have received a downvote (which is totally fine!) but if at all possible I would appreciate some feedback to understand what could be improved here and in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the client to redirect the browser on page load, to automate it add this at the end of the view before the `</html>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")";
</script>
```

Although I suspect there better solutions if we know the specific problem you are trying to overcome.

Comment: I tried to explain the motivation a bit better now. This seems to work, though (I have to check the other answers yet to get a better grasp of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing what u are trying to do,may be u can try something Like this

**TransactionIndex.cshtml**
`@model List<Transaction>
@Html.Partial("../Transaction/_Transaction",model)`

**Main.chtml**
`<a id="transactionLink" href='@Url.Action("GetMainTransactionView","Transaction")'/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use async ajax call from client to make another request after the view is rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
});
```

e.g.

```
jQuery.get( 'mywebsite/mycontroller/myaction')
```

Others are optional parameter.

This way you can trigger another action automatically and can handle the reponse of the request in success callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.get( 'mywebsite/mycontroller/myaction', {id:1}, onSuccess );
});
function onSuccess(response){
  // add logic to do whatever from response
}
```

Comment: Would this have any advantage over using <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")";
</script> as suggested in another answer?

Comment: @pablo your code fire as soon as JS downloaded and samir's code will fire after DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: Ok, I see... I will try to see if I can make both work, it will probably come in handy in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Anirudha is right, and major difference is the behavior of these two codes, window.location completely redirects you to new page while async ajax won't redirect you, it is called from the page and the page won't be left until explicitly mentioned to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to check the status of your long running request. Once it has completed you can redirect.

Add an action that reuturns the current status of your operation, e.g.

```
public JsonResult GetLoadStatus(){
    //Get status from somewhere
    bool isLoaded = ...
    return Json(isLoaded, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On your page, assuming you have jQuery (haven't tested this):

```
<div id="LoadStatus">Loading...</div>


<script>
    var loadingCompleted = false;

    function checkStatus(){
        $.get('/MyController/GetLoadStatus')
            .done(function(isLoaded){ 
                if(isLoaded){
                    loadingCompleted = true;
                    window.location.href = "/resulturl";
                }
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert("Error getting load status");
            })
            .always(function(){
                //Whether the call to your GetLoadStatus method failed or succeeded, always check again in 1 second.

                if(loadingCompleted === false){
                    setTimeout(checkStatus, 1000);
                }
            });
    }

    checkStatus();
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting! My first approach was to do something like this, but I could never really make it work. I will also try to make this approach work (if only to learn).